# code::blocks doesn't support JNI macros?

Tags: java, macros, java-native-interface, codeblocks

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_Func(....) {
  ....
}
```

I get unsatisfied link error when i try to run the java program with macros *(JNIEXPORT and JNICALL)* in the native code. But when i remove the macros,i get no exception. Is it that the IDE *Code::Blocks* doesn't support JNI macros ? If it supports what should i do to enable them ?

*Note :* I don't get a error or warning related to the macros defined . It just fails the run,as it gives me the unsatisfied link error.

*EDIT :*

Stacktrace :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:  keylogger.TestKeys.initializeJNIVars()V
    at keylogger.TestKeys.initializeJNIVars(Native Method)
    at keylogger.TestKeys.main(TestKeys.java:22)
```

But before throwing this exception,it prints a line from the native code. The problem is really the macros.

Comment: The mascros are required to satisfy the JNI linkage. Whatever the problem is, the solution cannot involve removing them.

Answer (score 1):

If the source compiles and the DLL is created, then there is nothing wrong with Code::Blocks. Code::Blocks uses gcc, and gcc can create JNI DLLs with no problem

If you getting this error when you are running the Java class, then make sure you have placed the DLL inside the `java.library.path`

### Edit

You need to add these two options on `Project->Build options->Linker Settings->Other Linker Options` to make it work:

`-Xlinker --add-stdcall-alias`

Comment: when i omit the the JNI macros and build the dll and run the same java program with the same library path,i get no exceptions of the type Unsatisfied link error. This is the problem. Why is that ?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: see the edit. But the stacktrace is printed after a statement from the native code is printed. It  is not that ,java is unable to find the library. The problem is really the macros b'coz if i remove the macros the program works fine

Comment: [nothing changed after adding the those 2 options](http://i46.tinypic.com/pxbw9.jpg)

Comment: This is what I used for testing it: http://pastie.org/4049524 Maybe you can use it as a template

Comment: Yes, it works fine. I used the CodeBlocks installer that contains MinGW and I'm on Windows XP